# Deploying angular 5 application to Amazon

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, angular5

I have made an angular 5 application and want to publish it to the production server that is hosted in Amazon EC2 (MongoDB and Node back-end are also running on there).
Does anyone have a good tutorial or tips how to deploy angular 5 application to production?

Comment: Why using `EC2` for a SPA? Please check [How Do I Configure an S3 Bucket for Static Website Hosting?](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/static-website-hosting.html) before going forward with `EC2` research.

Comment: That is why I am asking for advice. I read from lots of places that for static website S3 is a good solution. So correct me if I am wrong: The angular 5 app should be set up in the S3 bucket and the node backend with mongoDB should be running on EC2 instance ?

Comment: Exactly! I will give you another advice: instead of using `EC2` for your back-end you should check `AWS Lambda` to run you back-end [serverless](https://aws.amazon.com/serverless).

Comment: Thank you very much I will look into that option as well. Just for future projects, when would one use EC2 for deploying a web service?

Comment: As soon as your traffic is so high that the serverless approach generates more costs than having n `EC2` instances. So in my point of view its a matter of costs... as usual :-D

Comment: Thank you very much for the information, appreciate it ! :)

Comment: You can also check out this boilerplate: https://github.com/maciejtreder/angular-universal-pwa   I created it ESPECIALLY for such use-case. It can be deployed on AWS Lambda - so your environment would be super-cheap (or even cost-less) ;)

Answer (score 0):

This is a generic Question and to answer that hosting it as static site on s3 would be good idea. Referring to [this blog](https://medium.com/wolox-driving-innovation/deploy-your-angularjs-app-to-aws-s3-with-ssl-3635a62533ab) would help.

Now as for backend of node js to hosted on [Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) as per comments can be a good idea but it depends on your requirement if you are satisfied with `ec2` there is nothing wrong with using it.

Regarding MongoDB you can use separate `EC2`Instance cluster depending on your requirement, you can use [AWS quick start guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quickstart/latest/mongodb/welcome.html) for deploying Mongo clusters too via CloudFormation.